# Dynamic Cascading DropDowns in SharePoint

Tags: dynamic, sharepoint-2010, cascadingdropdown

I am working with ASAP.Net4.0 C# and SharePoint 2010. My requirement is I need a web part that display a empty textbox to start off with. User enter a number and that number of DropDowns get created dynamically.There is no problem uptil this point.

Lets assume user enters 5 in the textbox so 5 DropDows are created dynamically.

Now all the DropDowns have to be cascading.My problem is When ever i change value of any Drop Down it causes postback and binds all DropDowns again. I want that if user say select 3rd Drop Down then Drop Down 1 and DropDown 2 shouldn't be re bound or changed but all the DropDowns after DropDown 3 must be updated. As in here DropDown 4 should be updated with new value selected in DropDown 3 and DropDown 5 will have no items as there is no selection in DropDown 4.

Please guide.

Comment: Friends I have solution to this problem now. Let me know if any one needs.Thanks

Comment: good , as so often think about JQuery too http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Best Free JQuery based Solution

www.spcascade.org